# How to find the syntax error for tr utility

Tags: linux, ubuntu, tr

I am trying to make a file but I keep getting this error

```
tr: extra operand ' ' 
./homework: line2: syntax error near unexpected token '|'
./homework: line '| tr ' \t' '\n\n' \ '
```

Here is my file contents

```
tr ['a-z'] ['A-Z'] < practice \ 
| tr ' \t' '\n\n' \ 
| sed '/^$/d' \ 
| sort \ 
| tee x-sor.out
```

The error is said to be in line 2 and I cant tell what the problem is or apparently syntax

But if anyone is curious yes it is tr ' \t' that's what was used from my textbook

Comment: You're missing a quote in `tr ['a-z']`. Also you don't need the square brackets, and if you use them they should be inside the quotes.

Comment: oh sorry made an error when writing out the question @Barmar

Comment: Make sure the backslashes are the last character on each line, with no spaces after them.

Comment: The whole point is that it's escaping the newline, so that everything will be treated as a single command.

Comment: Oh wow!! I didnt realize that the extra invisible space will cause a syntax error. Thank you!!! It was driving me insane @Barmar

Comment: The first error message tells you that there's an extra argument containing a single space. That's what backslash-space creates.

Comment: The syntax error on line 2 is because you can't start a command with `|`.

Comment: It's as if you wrote `tr 'a-z' 'A-Z' < practice '  '`

Comment: Ahhhhh I see what you mean now so when it says extra space ' ' then look where extra spaces would be @Barmar

Comment: You should `cat homework.sh` and paste the entire file with your question. Also see [How to use Shellcheck](http://github.com/koalaman/shellcheck), [How to debug a bash script?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/155551/56041) (U&L.SE), [How to debug a bash script?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/951336/608639) (SO), [How to debug bash script?](http://askubuntu.com/q/21136) (AskU), [Debugging Bash scripts](http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_02_03.html), etc.